# R calling Fortran subroutine

Tags: r, fortran, subroutine, forecasting

I understood that `.Fortran` from following code invokes Fortran subroutine, but why we are using `C_` for subroutine name here? Few other subroutine calling examples I looked over internet are simply `"stl"`, can someone please help me with why `C_stl` instead of `stl`?

```
 z <- .Fortran(C_stl, x, n,
          as.integer(period),
          as.integer(s.window),
          as.integer(t.window),
          as.integer(l.window),
          s.degree, t.degree, l.degree,
          nsjump = as.integer(s.jump),
          ntjump = as.integer(t.jump),
          nljump = as.integer(l.jump),
          ni = as.integer(inner),
          no = as.integer(outer),
          weights = double(n),
          seasonal = double(n),
          trend = double(n),
          double((n+2*period)*5))
```

Comment: The subroutine is not called `C_stl`. `C_stl` is a variable containing the Fortran subroutine name as character. So if you want to call a subroutine `stl` use either `"stl"` or set `C_stl <- "stl"` and use variable `C_stl`.

Comment: @Bhas: That was understanding, but when I look at code from link https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/stl.R, I am not seeing any assignment like you said, but I am positive C_Stl calling stl.f from https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/stl.f.

Comment: don't know the answer, but (1) `C_stl` [only appears in the code base in this one place](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?q=C_stl&ref=cmdform); (2) maybe related to [this](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?q=F77_SUB%28stl%29&type=Code)?

Comment: @BenBolker: Thanks! I will wait and see if any input from community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C_stl` is an object in the `stats` package containing auxiliary information about the Fortran subroutine. It's not exported, so to see it you'll have to type `stats:::C_stl`.

```
> stats:::C_stl
$name
[1] "stl"

$address
<pointer: 0x000000000f87b950>
attr(,"class")
[1] "RegisteredNativeSymbol"

$dll
DLL name: stats
Filename: E:/apps/R/R-3.1.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll
Dynamic lookup: FALSE

$numParameters
[1] 18

attr(,"class")
[1] "FortranRoutine"   "NativeSymbolInfo"
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite true. The NAMESPACE file, as I mentioned in my first answer, prefixes the names of all C/Fortran routines in the stats library with C_stl. If the .Fortran of the OP works with C_stl, then it isn't necessary to use `stats:::C_stl`. And doesn't the syntax `stats:::C_stl` only work with functions with R syntax?

Comment: The `stl` function knows where to find `C_stl` because they both live in the environment of the `stats` package. `C_stl` doesn't have to be exported for this to happen. Note that the usual first argument to `.C`/`.Fortran` is a _string_; functions supplied by the base R distribution are a bit more rigorous than that and use a classed object instead.

Comment: I am leaning more towards this answer. Sorry @Bhas, I know you put in lot of effort, but this answer seems more correct.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching I believe I found the answer. Look in the the NAMESPACE file in the directory `<path to R sources>/src/library/stats`.

You'll see that all C/Fortran routines are referred to with names prefixed with `C_`, This appears to be done by `useDynLib`.